# javascript and html logic statements

Tags: javascript, html, logic

So for a project I was assigned to make a simple html page that links to a javascript file. On this page there are 3 integer inputs and 2 buttons. The buttons test whether the integers will make a triangle or not, and the second button will test whether the integers make a right triangle.

Right now I am still having trouble with the first button.
I am using the algorithm:
    a+b>c
    a+c>b
    b+c>a

if all of these are true then the statement should return as "It forms a triangle" and the else should state that it would not return a triangle.

I think I have the logic and the set-up right but when I go to test all conditions will return true.
Any help would be much appreciated. Sorry if my code is kind of sloppy or doesn't make sense I'm still learning.

Thanks again.

HTML File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Triangle Tester</title>
<script src="project3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div>
<h1>Triangle Tester</h1>
<p>Please input the length (integer) of the first side of the triangle: </p>
    <input id="t1" type="text" size="3" />

<p>Please input the length (integer) of the second side of the triangle: </p>
    <input id="t2" type="text" size="3" />

<p>Please input the length (integer) of the third side of the triangle: </p>
    <input id="t3" type="text" size="3" />

<br/>
<span id="answer"></span>
<br/>

<button onclick="compute1();">Can these three sizes form a triangle?</button>
<button onclick="compute2();">Can these three sizes form a right triangle?</button>    
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript File:

```
// JavaScript Document
function compute1()
{
    var in1 = document.getElementById("t1"); //A
    var in2 = document.getElementById("t2"); //B
    var in3 = document.getElementById("t3"); //C
    var ans = document.getElementById("answer");

    if( (in1.value+in2.value>in3.value)&&
        (in1.value+in3.value>in2.value)&&
        (in2.value+in3.value>in1.value) )
    {
        var result = "These three sides can form a triangle!";
        ans.innerHTML = result;
    }

    else
    {
        var result2 = "These three sides cannot form a triangle!";
        ans.innerHTML = result2;    
    }
}

function compute2()
{
    return 0;   
}
```

So any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: What if a, b and c are all the same integer, wouldn't that form a triangle ?

Comment: Anyway, the value of an input is always a string, so when you do `"2" + "3"` you end up with `"23"` and not `5` like you're expecting

Comment: What values are you getting from the individual variables, can you debug/alert and check?

Comment: Any IDEs you recommend to debug js? I've been using dreamweaver but it doesnt have a lot of developer tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to parse the values into numbers - at the moment all inputs are text and cannot be used to calculate the result correctly. Assuming your algorithm is correct, Use:

```
var in1Val=parseInt(in1.value);
var in2Val=parseInt(in2.value);
var in3Val=parseInt(in3.value);

    if( (in1Val+in2.value>in3Val)&&
        (in1Val+in3Val>in2Val)&&
        (in2Val+in3Val>in1Val) )...
```

if there is a risk that the input values might not be numerical, you can use parseFloat and check for NaN being returned (if there is a non-integer based input).  Hope this helps Gavrif

Comment: This worked perfectly! Was not aware that input is all string, fixed it immediately.